# Salesforce LiveAgent Domain Whitelisting issue

Tags: salesforce

I am using Salesforce LiveAgent Chat, and below are our configurations,

Chat Deployments:

1. Allow access to Pre-Chat API: yes
2. Permitted Domain: I have 4 domains each on new line formatted as "domainname.com"

When a request is placed from my livechat application: `https://d.la1-c2-iad.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Visitor/Availability?Availability.ids=<agent_id>&deployment_id=<chat_id>&org_id=<org_id>`

I am gettting response as `{"messages":[{"type":"Error","message":{"text":"Domain is not whitelisted for this deployment"}}]}`

Though I am getting exception in browser console, Generic Agent Chat is working fine, However Dedicated Agent chat(with specific agent_id) it is not working.

I tried removing permitted domains from chat deployment setting and error no longer appear.